# Access-Control-Allow-Origin added to firebase.json but missing from the file response header

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Below is my simple firebase.json. If I read the docs right it should tag all files with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Unfortunately none of the files are being tagged resulting in the error:

> Imported resource from origin 'https://gaspush.firebaseapp.com' has
>   been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Could someone take a look and let me know how to properly allow all files to all endpoints?

```
{
  "firebase": "gaspush",
  "headers": [ {
    "source" : “**”,
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
    } ]
  } ],
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of `firebase-tools` are you using? `v1.1.0` is the first to upload headers I believe

Comment: I'm at version 1.2.0

Comment: The firebase.json here looks good (other than the `“` instead of `"` chars on that line, but I don't think that's the issue) - could you provide an example of it not working; the link is for a site that's been removed. If you don't want to share publicly, you can email support@firebase.com

Comment: Once I changed the quotes it worked. I must have pasted that from the docs page. Thanks much.

Answer (score 19):

This is maybe no longer relevant to the original question, but I ran into a similar issue with the new version of Firebase. I had accidentally placed `"headers"` section outside of the `"hosting"` key.

The below snippet worked for me.

```
"hosting": {
    "public": ".",
    "headers": [ {
        "source" : "**",
        "headers" : [{
          "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value" : "*"
        }]
    }]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is why nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: I Tried This And It Didnt Work, i added it to my firebase.json file, and it doesnt work