# cros domain issue . need to call get request to firebase hosted angular2 app

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting

I am trying to get value from angular 2 app hosted in firebase .when we try it is showing error

Failed to load

```
https://url/?a1=123&a2=milla: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
index.hmtl:22 XHR finished loading: GET "https://url/?a1=123&a2=milla".
loadXMLDoc @ index.hmtl:22
onclick @ index.hmtl:8
```

This is my firebase.json data

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/timestamp",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source" : "index.html",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
      } ]
    } ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my ajax code to request data from firebase hosted angular2 app

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://url/?a2=123&a1=milla", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Are you testing it on your own computer at localhost?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927956/access-control-allow-origin-added-to-firebase-json-but-missing-from-the-file-res?rq=1

Comment: in my localhost and my server

Comment: Looks like you only set cors for "index.html"

Comment: i changed to "**" and not working

Comment: Check in developer tools that the header is set.

Comment: after adding index.html to "**" one problem is solved